# Delete between with a button and $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, get, between

I'm trying to setup a button that will delete all the rows we loaded on this run but it's not working.

PHP:

```
if(isset( $_GET['startID'], $_GET['endID']))
{
     $sql_query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id BETWEEN " .$_GET['startID'] . " AND " . $_GET['endID'] . ";";
     mysql_query($sql_query);
     header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Button:

```
<a onClick="javascript: return confirm('Are you sure?');" href='index.php?startID=<?php echo $firstID; ?>&endID=<?php echo $lastID; ?>'>Delete</a>
```

Button redirects to: `index.php?startID=11111&endID=22222`

The button is passing the values but they're not getting deleted from the database. Can anyone point me to the mistake?

Comment: are you sure the connection with database is well established and working?

Comment: Look at this `isset( $_GET['startID'], $_GET['endID'])` and `echo $sql_query` and copy the string and run into the database and let us know what is shows at the successful run.

Comment: Of course, I've replace the real id's with 11111 and 22222. I receive the real first and last ID's.

Comment: @FrayneKonok look mate: http://take.ms/9sg3z.
It all worked with PhpMyAdmin (I did like you said, echo'd the query and ran it directly).
What's wrong?

Comment: The security side of me would not recommend passing a `$_GET` parameter into a SQL transaction..

Comment: So there is no error at all, Check the database connection as @Rohith said.

Comment: @FrayneKonok You guys are right, endless coding nights and I forgot running the query. Added `$resultDel = $conn->query($sql_query);` and it now works. Thanks! @JaeGeeTee, what's wrong with that mate?

Comment: @Ricardo depending upon where your application is deployed you could open yourself up to sql injection.

Comment: @JaeGeeTee says, Ha ha ha.. Anyone can Delete those rows from database by the SQL Injection. You Have to use PDO for the security of database statements / queries.

Comment: @FrayneKonok, is PDO as simple as `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;d......`? Found it on some website.

Comment: `PDO` is simple and easy also secure.

Comment: @FrayneKonok You may be right that it is that simple.  However, depending on how you did this you could really make it a pain to scale, check: https://12factor.net/config.  However, on top of their being an inherent bad practice of pumping a string straight into a MySQL transaction, you're also adding complexity to the situation with the recommended fix.  So, I disagree with going the route of the PDO.

Comment: The security issues go beyond just the query.  @Ricardo When you use data as a string input in another context, it must be escaped properly.  You're echoing data into a query string, in HTML... those are two context wrapped within each other and your code ignores both.  Then, in your PHP, you have the opportunity to fundamentally separate the data from the query using a parepared/parameterized query.  This guarantees that injection attacks cannot occur on your database, if it is always used.  Use it.  Those goes beyond security... your code will sometimes not work if left as-is.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem you need to start Debugging yourself. What you really need to do is-

1. Check the database connection is established or not.
2. Checkout the Condition is correct or not that is applied, You can use a simple echo for this.
3. echo the query string and run into the `phpMyAdmin` and see is there anything miss use or others.

> These are the suggestion for all the **OP** who ask this type of
>   questions. We are always here to help you where you get stuck.

Comment: I never thought about this approach. That's why I like StackOverflow :) Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

Try for instead:

```
if(isset( $_GET['startID'], $_GET['endID']))
{
  for($i=$_GET['startID'];$i<=$_GET['endID'];$i++){
     $sql_query="DELETE * FROM users WHERE id=" .$i. ";";
     mysql_query($sql_query);                            
  }
  header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: Your Idea was good but you also think about the execution time. You can better use the query string in an array and after the loop executes once. [Not good].

Comment: Never concatenate data directly into a query.  It's horribly insecure.

Comment: @Brad DID you mean `id=" .$i. ";";`??